# Automate Custom Report Export in Shopify without Shopify Apps

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to automate some process that requires downloading a custom report created from Shopify Admin daily. I tried resort to Shopify API to manually pull orders via the Order API, however, the process requires going through pagination which took several minutes to go through a few thousands of orders while it will only a few seconds to manually export the csv file from the Shopify Admin page.

So I'm just wondering if it's possible to implement a service that export those custom reports that were created in Shopify Admin into a csv file without human interaction?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just write some Javascript to run in the admin that will do the custom report for you, without pushing all the buttons you'd push manually. You can fake being human that way and automate things. Once you have that straightened away, you could setup a service that would run that scripting automatically when you wanted, say on a schedule.

Of course, the old pokey way you pointed out is probably way easier, but as you say, it takes minutes and hey, who has minutes to spare!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it can solve your problem. I use a cloud data platform (not Shopify Apps) called [Acho](https://acho.io/) to retrieve data from Shopify and then export the report to Google Sheets automatically. Sometimes, I also create my own reports on the platform before exporting them to Google Sheets. I think it can somehow reduce lots of manual works. You can try its free trial if you are interested.